# Execute command via ssh

Tags: bash, unix

I want to kill process. Without kill cmd it works fine. But with kill cmd i get:

```
grep: invalid option -- 'S'
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try 'grep --help' for more information.
awk: cmd. line:1: {print
awk: cmd. line:1:       ^ unexpected newline or end of string
kill: usage: kill [-s sigspec | -n signum | -sigspec] pid | jobspec ... or kill -l [sigspec]
```

Doesn't work:

```
ssh someUser@someHost kill $(ps -aux | grep 'screen -S cats' | awk '{print $2}')
```

Works fine:

```
ssh someUser@someHost ps -aux | grep 'screen -S cats' | awk '{print $2}'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command substitution runs `ps` *locally*, to produce the argument for the remote `kill` command.

To make the command substitution run remotely, quote the *entire* string (which is a good idea; you generally don't want `ssh` having to figure out how to join its arguments into a single command).

```
# Using $'...', which may contain escaped single quotes
ssh someUser@someHost $'kill $(ps -aux | awk \'/screen -S cats/ {print $2}\''
```

or

```
# Using standard double quotes, but making the user responsible
# for escaping any dollar signs that need to be passed literally.
ssh someUser@someHost "kill \$(ps -aux | awk '/screen -S cats/ {print \$2}'"
```

Comment: A quoted heredoc is another approach worth showcasing. (`ssh someUser@someHost 'bash -s' <<'EOF'`; `kill $(ps -aux | grep 'screen -S cats' | awk '{print $2}')` on its own line; then `EOF` on a third).

Comment: I like to avoid those, as inevitably someone tries to pass a script via standard input that itself tries to read from standard input.

Comment: Thank u very much guys!